# How to Auto-scale custom metrics uploaded in Azure Application Insights and on what basis?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

We have created on application to upload some custom metrics to Azure Application Insights. I need to know how we can Auto-scale this custom metrics in Azure and on what basis auto-scale can be done?

What can be auto-scaled and how we can do it on what basis?

Comment: Did you ever accomplish this? I'm interested in doing the same thing.

Comment: Azure Autoscale does not currently support custom metrics via Azure Application Insights.

Answer (score 0):

From azure cli, 1 example way to achieve it is:

```
az monitor autoscale rule create -g <myrg> \
    --autoscale-name test \
    --scale out 1 \
    --condition "'<metricNamespace>' <metricName> > 80 total 5m"
```

Somehow, a single quote (within the double quotes for the `--condition`) is needed for `metricNamespace`.

Definition of the condition parser is seen [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/master/src/azure-cli/azure/cli/command_modules/monitor/grammar/metric_alert/MetricAlertCondition.g4)